# Webfocus - HGETC vs. hard-coded date

Tags: webfocus

I have this line of code:

```
TDY_DATE/HMDYYs = HGETC(8,'HMDYYs');
```

Its used to generate a report based on today's date.

How can I revise this line so I can hard-code a date other than today?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simply use a FPRINT to assign hardcoded date to your variable

-SET TDY_DATE = FPRINT(HARDCODED_DATE, 'HMDYYs', 'A8');